# Why does Jinja2 ignore initial variable formatting?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am writing a Python application that runs a Flask webserver. The webserver returns template pages to the user. Take an example line from my html file:    `<div class="column" style= {{ column.color }}>`  with the corresponding color variable:    `"background: lightgreen"`  For some reason unbeknownst to me, Jinja2 renders that line of html as: `<div class="column" style="background:" lightgreen="">` and not the expected: `<div class="column" style="background:lightgreen">`

The reason this matters is because what it renders is not correct css and so the background is not set to the lightgreen color like i intend. Why does this happen and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed quotes in the style attribute:

```
<div class="column" style="{{ column.color }}">
```